# How to execute an arbitrary number of async tasks in sequential order?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function:

```
async Task RefreshProfileInfo(List<string> listOfPlayers)

// For each player in the listOfPlayers, checks an in-memory cache if we have an entry.
// If we have a cached entry, do nothing.
// If we don't have a cached entry, fetch from backend via an API call.
```

This function is called very frequently, like:

```
await RefreshProfileInfo(playerA, playerB, playerC)
```

or

```
await RefreshProfileInfo(playerB, playerC, playerD)
```

or

```
await RefreshProfileInfo(playerE, playerF)
```

Ideally, if the players do not overlap each other, the calls should not affect each other (requesting PlayerE and PlayerF should not block the request for PlayerA, PlayerB, PlayerC). However, if the players DO overlap each other, the second call should wait for the first (requesting PlayerB, PlayerC, PlayerD, should wait for PlayerA, PlayerB, PlayerC to finish).

However, if that isn't possible, at the very least I'd like all calls to be sequential. (I think they should still be async, so they don't block *other* unrelated parts of the code).

Currently, what happens is each RefreshProfileInfo runs in parallel, which results in hitting backend every time (9 times in this example).

Instead, I want to execute them sequentially, so that only the first call hits the backend, and subsequent calls just hit cache.

What data structure/approach should I use? I'm having trouble figuring out how to "connect" the separate calls to each other. I've been playing around with Task.WhenAll() as well as SemaphoreSlim, but I can't figure out how to use them properly.

**Failed attempt**

The idea behind my failed attempt was to have a helper class where I could call a function, SequentialRequest(Task), and it would sequentially run all tasks invoked in this manner.

```
List<Task> waitingTasks = new List<Task>();
object _lock = new object();

public async Task SequentialRequest(Task func)
{
    var waitingTasksCopy = new List<Task>();

    lock (_lock)
    {
        waitingTasksCopy = new List<Task>(waitingTasks);
        waitingTasks.Add(func); // Add this task to the waitingTasks (for future SequentialRequests)
    }

    // Wait for everything before this to finish
    if (waitingTasksCopy.Count > 0)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(waitingTasksCopy);
    }

    // Run this task
    await func;
}
```

I thought this would work, but "func" is either run instantly (instead of waiting for earlier tasks to finish), or never run at all, depending on how I call it.

If I call it using this, it runs instantly:

```
async Task testTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(4000);
}
```

If I call it using this, it never runs:

```
Task testTask = new Task(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(4000);
});
```

Comment: It's not clear that you can "connect" the calls. A common caching technique is to save the date/time when updating the cached data. On subsequent calls check the cache date/time. If it is acceptably fresh you're good to go, otherwise it will refresh the cache and return the new results. You might want to modify the call to include an `maximumAge` in milliseconds. A value of `0` will always force a refresh.

Comment: @HABO thanks for the reply. My issue is handling the case where *nothing* is in the cache and a dozen calls come in requesting the *same* player's info. I don't want to hit the backend a dozen times in that case for the *same* player.

Comment: An empty cache should have a `null` date/time. By adding a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to the cache you can serialize access: the first thread to hit the cache will force an update while the others wait. Once the cache is updated and the lock released the other requests should, assuming they have a reasonable `maximumAge` value, lock/read/unlock the cache in a brief period. (You can have a cache and lock per player.)

Comment: Using `await` on `RefreshProfileInfo` above should make it sequential already. What is inside `RefreshProfileInfo`? Are you awaiting to make the back-end call complete first?

Comment: @HABO I see, thanks. I'd have to give it more thought, but I could see that approach working possibly. I was just really hoping to avoid locks to avoid the possibility of deadlocks. Just for context, I anticipate thousands of concurrent players being connected to this server.
IlianPinzon yes, I'm awaiting the backend call. The awaits are called at different times; I just put them in a row for the writeup.

Comment: If there is one lock _to rule them all_ you can't deadlock, but performance will suffer. One lock per player can't deadlock as long as a task doesn't try to lock more than one player at a time. If multiple players are locked by a single task then you need to either enforce an order on the locks that precludes deadlocks or handle deadlocks when they arise.

Comment: I do not get it..... if you want them to be sequential then why make them async in the first place?

Comment: Your code is already running `RefreshProfileInfo` sequentially, one after the other, and not concurrently.

Comment: HABO - hmm that might be tricky to enforce an order on the locks, because I fetch players in batches, so I would have multiple players per lock.
Darkonekt - because they are called from different places in the code (in response to clients requesting profile info). I don't want one player's request to block another player's request if they are requesting *different* players.
@StephenCleary sorry that my example was misleading. I was just trying to show that I'm calling it in multiple places. I'll edit my post. I'm calling RefreshProfileInfo at separate times (possibly separate threads).

Comment: Darkonekt - actually I revised my post. Ideally a player's request wouldn't block another player's request if they're requesting different players, but I understand that's tricky to implement. At the very least, I don't want it to block *other* parts of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's why your current attempt doesn't work:

```
// Run this task
await func;
```

The comment above is not describing what the code is doing. In the asynchronous world, a `Task` represents some operation *that is already in progress*. Tasks are not "run" by using `await`; `await` it a way for the current code to "asynchronously wait" for a task to *complete*. So no function signature taking a `Task` is going to work; the task is already in progress before it's even passed to that function.

Your question is actually about caching asynchronous operations. One way to do this is to cache the `Task<T>` itself. Currently, your cache holds the results (`T`); you can change your cache to hold the asynchronous operations that retrieve those results (`Task<T>`). For example, if your current cache type is `ConcurrentDictionary<PlayerId, Player>`, you could change it to `ConcurrentDictionary<PlayerId, Task<Player>>`.

With a cache of tasks, when your code checks for a cache entry, it will find an existing entry if the player data is loaded *or has started loading*. Because the `Task<T>` represents some asynchronous operation that is already in progress (or has already completed).

A couple of notes for this approach:

1. This only works for in-memory caches.
2. Think about how you want to handle errors. A naive cache of `Task<T>` will also cache *error* results, which is usually not desired.

The second point above is the trickier part. When an error happens, you'd probably want some additional logic to *remove* the errored task from the cache. Bonus points (and additional complexity) if the error handling code prevents an errored task from getting into the cache in the first place.

> at the very least I'd like all calls to be sequential

Well, that's much easier. `SemaphoreSlim` is the asynchronous replacement for `lock`, so you can use a shared `SemaphoreSlim`. Call `await mySemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();` at the beginning of `RefreshProfileInfo`, put the body in a `try`, and in the `finally` block at the end of `RefreshProfileInfo`, call `mySemaphoreSlim.Release();`. That will limit all calls to `RefreshProfileInfo` to running sequentially.

Comment: Thank you - SemaphoreSlim as you've described works perfectly for my situation. Thanks for clarifying about the "await func" being wrong. I take it there's no way to pass a "delayed" task that is started & awaited at a later time.

Comment: @Brent: Yes and no. You can pass a `Func<Task>` and run that, and that would work perfectly as a "delayed" asynchronous function. But I'm not sure how well that would fit with the rest of the method's logic around the list of tasks.

Comment: I see, thanks! I'll try that when I revisit this. The SemaphoreSlim solution is working great for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one of my projects. I had multiple threads call a single method and they all made IO calls when not found in cache. What you want to do is to add the `Task` to your cache and then `await` it. Subsequent calls will then just read the result once the task completes.

Example:

```
private Task RefreshProfile(Player player)
{
     // cache is of type IMemoryCache
     return _cache.GetOrCreate(player, entry => 
     {
        // expire in 30 seconds
        entry.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30);
        return ActualRefreshCodeThatReturnsTask(player);
     });
}
```

Then just `await` in your calling code

```
await Task.WhenAll(RefreshProfile(Player a), RefreshProfile(Player b), RefreshProfile(Player c));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It sounds like you understand the problem I'm having! I'm not sure if I can easily adapt my code to your IMemoryCache structure, since my underlying code actually fetch profiles in batches rather than a single player. (ActualRefreshCodeThatReturnsTask seems like it's called on a single player)